# Value of 'arguments' of fat arrow function inside callback giving unexpected values

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

See the below snippets:

**Snippet #1:**

```js
let fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile(process.argv[2], "utf8", (error, data) => console.log(arguments));
```

---

**Snippet #2:**

```js
let fs = require("fs");
fs.readFile(process.argv[2], "utf8", (error, data) => console.log(error, data));
```

---

**Expected log:** 
Values of `(error, data)`, for example like:

`null 'console.log("HELLO WORLD");\r\n'`

---

When you try both these snippets, you will find that the **Snippet #1** executes and logs some unexpected values for `console.log(arguments)` but `console.log(error, data)` logs proper values; values of `(error, data)`.

Why and What was the value that is being logged for Snippet #1?

Comment: Should those snippets be runnable? Coz, `require` will not work

Comment: See also [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **No binding of arguments**
>
> Arrow functions do not bind an arguments object Thus, arguments is
>   simply a reference to the name in the enclosing scope.

[From: MDN - Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_arguments)

If you wish to use variadic arguments inside an arrow function, use the rest parameters syntax:

```
fs.readFile(process.argv[2], "utf8", (...args) => console.log(args));
```

Answer (score 5):

@Tamas is smack on,

But a little tip for the OP, if you ever wonder what new javascript features from ES6 etc are doing.  I paste the code into Babeljs.io try it out bit.

eg. Your code ->

https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Clatest%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&code=fs.readFile(process.argv%5B2%5D%2C%20%22utf8%22%2C%20(error%2C%20data)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(arguments))%3B%0D%0A

and then @Tamas code ->https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Clatest%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&code=fs.readFile(process.argv%5B2%5D%2C%20%22utf8%22%2C%20(...args)%20%3D%3E%20console.log(args))%3B

Comment: You've opened my eyes :)